# How can I capture iPhone console logs programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6

I have seen two applications in Appstore named Console ([Console](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/console/id317676250?mt=8)) and System Console ([System Console](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/system-console/id431158981?mt=8)) to capture iPhone console logs. Does anyone have idea on how they are doing it? If so can you guide me so that I can capture them programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can access them (seen it with HockeyApp) with the ASL, the Apple System Log facility

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/

Comment: Thank you. If I follow the above process, can I capture dropped/failed calls information?